# Avoiding Inequality Joins - BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

Is there a fast solution for finding overlapping intervals instead of using costly inequality joins in BigQuery ?

> ON (A.start <= B.End) AND (B.Start <= A.END)

Comment: why does it cost more this syntax over other?

Comment: do you have some specific use case in mind? can you share some details?